# Level of MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, flash-cs5, movieclip, layer

When creating some extended MovieClip to the stage using AS on Actions of some frame, on which layer this MovieClip is created? On layer where Actions were? If I wanna move it down, for example, can I simply move the Actions layer? And by the way, one more question, what if I would not create Actions layer and write all the code on some used one? :SS

Comment: Move the action layer from where to where... and for what?

It doesn't make any sense

Comment: I mean hierarchically :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you add objects through ActionScript it will not consider your layers it will add on the top of the display list. and for traversing into movieclips u can use MoveiClip(root) or MovieClip(parent). check out addChildAt() and addChild() methods of ActionScript for more info.

Comment: Just to complement this good answer: layers do not actually exist, it is a concept only available through Flash Professional. In the end, Flash Professional converts its layers in addChild() requests. If you want to regroup several graphics through ActionScript in one "layer" to easily move the group up or down in the display list with addChildAt(), you can add them in a Sprite object, and then move the Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope u mean nested MovieClips**

http://www.quip.net/blog/2007/flash/trust-me-as3-its-a-movie-clip